# Loop iteration with time interval before passing value to included function

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to figure out how to set time out for function inside the loop iteration in Ionic TypeScript application.

`setInterval` makes equal time interval with calling the function in endless repetition:

```
   setInterval(() => {
      this.myFunc1(val);
   }, 800);
```

`setTimeout` gives required result if listed sequentially:

```
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.myFunc1(val);
   }, 800); 

   setTimeout(() => {
      this.myFunc1(val);
   }, 1200);
```

but how to loop with time interval trough the updated list and wait while pass second value `val` to the function, or call `myFunc1` when it will be finished in previous iteration:

```
 async myFunc2() {
    for (let val of this.myValueList) {
        /// wait for 5 sec or wait for finishing process, then pass value calling function:  
        this.myFunc1(val);          
    }
  }
```

Comment: No, setInterval doesn't makes equal time interval, it make some delay intervals which are indicative and never equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) is the correct choice here. What's missing is that you need to clear the interval. `setInterval` returns an id that you can pass to [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) which stops the iteration.

Here I'm passing data to `console.log`, waiting a second, then repeating till done.

```js
const myValueList = [5,6,7,8,9,10];

let i = 0;
const id = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(myValueList[i++]);
  if (i === myValueList.length) {
    clearInterval(id);
    console.log("done!");
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution for waiting approximately 5 seconds:

```js
const wait = t => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t));
```

and then in your code you can just do:

```js
async myFunc2() {
    for (let val of this.myValueList) {
        await wait(5000);
        this.myFunc1(val);
    }
}
```

---

If `myFunc1` is async, and you just want to wait for it to finish executing before continuing the loop, then you would just do:

```js
async myFunc2() {
    for (let val of this.myValueList) {
        await this.myFunc1(val);
    }
}
```